# mysql batch linux programming

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a table named my_table that contains rows for hash_value, file_name, file_contents, and id.

I have a program that accepts a hash value from the user.

I would like to take this value and create a mysql batch that will dump the file out to file_name

I can create a batch to dump the file contents using

```
SELECT file_contents INTO DUMPFILE 'myfilename' FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue';
```

but I have not been able to find a way to get file_name first and use that in the command.
I would also like a way to let my program know if the batch failed and why (no such hash in table, file exists already, etc)

pseudo code

```
@file_name = SELECT file_name FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue';
if @file_name is not empty
    SELECT file_contents INTO DUMPFILE @file_name FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue';
    // if file exists already then the error gets sent to stdout so I can determine that
else
    echo something to stdout so I know the user entered a value not in the table
endif
```

I am running this batch in the followng manner

```
mysql -h localhost -u theuser -pthepassword mydatabase < mybatch.sql
```

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I am getting closer.  I am able to set the file name using

`SELECT @filename:=file_name FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhahsvalue';`

but I get an error when trying to use this in my next statement
`SELECT file_contents INTO DUMPFILE @filename FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue';`

results in **You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

**EDIT 2:**
I can now get the file name (if it exists based on the hash) using this.  I am still working on the error reporting part, but this works well

```
SELECT @filename:=file_name FROM my_table WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue';
SET @query:=CONCAT("SELECT file_contents INTO DUMPFILE '",@filename,"' FROM mytable WHERE hash_value='myhashvalue'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

My not be the 'best' solution, but just added --verbose and then at the end 2>&1 to redirect stderr to stdout.  Can then parse the text for error codes.
ERROR 1064 if an invalid hash is entered, mysql failes on the execute
ERROR 1086 if the file already exists
Thank for looking

Comment: if you could add the answer here (in your answer) instead of in the question, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a program that accepts a hash value from the user.

An presumably there's a reason why you don't simply modify this program to call the SQL? If all it does is to read in a value then what utiity is it?

Use a mysql procedure to read the filename in, assign it to a variable and tun the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE extract (IN hash_in VARCHAR(100))
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE fname VARCHAR(100);
   SELECT file_name INTO fname FROM my_table WHERE hash_value=hash_in LIMIT 0,1;
   SELECT file_contents 
     INTO DUMPFILE fname 
     FROM my_table WHERE hash_value=hash_in;
END;
```

Comment: yes, this is a very simplified version representing one small issue I encountered as part of a very large project

I have limited MYSQL experience. I will work through adding the procedure. Thank you!